# In Ember.js, what's the idiomatic way to convert newlines in data to HTML BR elements?

Tags: html, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to figure out the best way to get Ember.js to convert special characters to properly formatted HTML. In this case, I have data that contains newlines that I'd like Ember.js/Handlebars to display as BR elements.

Following this example from http://williamhart.info/editing-markdown-with-emberjs.html :

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('breaklines', function(text) {
    text = Ember.Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(text);
    text = text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '<br>');
    return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(text);
});
```

. . . I was able to accomplish my goal, but I want to be sure I'm not overlooking some built-in functionality that does the same thing.

TIA.

Comment: You could style the text with a `white-space` value which honors the newlines, such as `pre-wrap` or `pre-line`.

Comment: @torazaburo , awesome!  Didn't know that property existed.  :-)  I wonder if there's something in Twitter Bootstrap that utilizes that.  Haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could style the text with a `white-space` value which honors the newlines, such as `pre-wrap` or `pre-line`.